# Defining types for a method in TypeScript which recursively maps values

Tags: typescript, recursion, types

I have a TypeScript function which takes an object, and recursively maps its values:

```
function mapValues<O, K extends keyof O, R>(object: O, transformation: (value: MappedValues<O[K]>) => R): { [key in K]: ResultValue<O, key, R>} {
    return Object.entries(object).reduce((prev, [key, value]) => {
        prev[key] = typeof value === 'object'
            ? mapValues(value as any, transformation)
            : transformation(value as MappedValues<O[K]>);

        return prev;
    }, {} as any)
}

type MappedValues<V> = V extends {[p: string]: infer U} ? MappedValues<U> : V
type ResultValue<O, K extends keyof O, R> = O[K] extends {[p: string]: infer U} ? ResultValue<O, K, U> : R

const foo = {
    bar: 'hello',
    baz: 'world',
    qux: {
        a: 'a',
        b: 'b'
    }
}

const result = mapValues(foo, (value) => value.length)
```

However, the type of `result` is `{bar: number, bar: number, qux: any}`, but I would like for `qux` to have the specific type `{a: number, b: number}`.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function mapValues<O, K extends keyof O, R>(object: O, transformation: (value: MappedValues<O[K]>) => R): { [key in K]: ResultValue<O, key, R>} {
    return Object.entries(object).reduce((prev, [key, value]) => {
        prev[key] = typeof value === 'object'
            ? mapValues(value, transformation)
            : transformation(value as MappedValues<O[K]>);

        return prev;
    }, {} as any)
}

type MappedValues<V> = V extends {[p: string]: infer U} ? MappedValues<U> : V
type ResultValue<O, K extends keyof O, R> = O[K] extends {[p: string]: infer U} ? { [key in keyof O[K]]: ResultValue<O[K], key, R>} : R
```